# Remove numbers after decimal point in c++ (without floor() function)

Tags: c++

How would i replicate the code below but without using the `floor()` function? I need to do this because i'm in a postion that i cannot use the `floor()` function

```
double quickExampleee = 3.1459038585;
std::cout << std::floor(quickExamplee  * 100.) / 100. << std::endl;
```

I've searched for answers all around and haven't been able to find anything? Anyways thanks for your time,

Comment: `static_cast<int>(quickExamplee  * 100.) / 100.`

Comment: Why can you not use the `floor()` function?

Answer (score 3):

What about using `std::setprecision` if you don't like to cast the numbers to int's, like

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(0) << quickExamplee << std::endl;
```

so to print out **3.14** you simply set precision to 2, like

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << quickExamplee << std::endl;
```

Comment: This works only for positive numbers. Its not equivalent to floor.
However, I start to wonder if the OP really meant floor() or simply wants to set the precision.

Comment: @pokey909 -- The real question is in the title -- he wants to print without (or limiting) the trailing digits.

Answer (score 2):

You could do `static_cast<int>(quickExampleee * 100.)` as long as the double is greater than 0.

Comment: It is supposed to be the replacement for the `floor` call, not the entired code.

Comment: @DimChtz: Don't be obtuse. Only the `floor` call has been replaced. This answer also does not contain the `std::cout` statement - does that also make it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
int myFloorForWhateverReason(double x) {
    if (x > 0.0)
        return (int)x;
    else
        return (int)(x - 0.5);
}

double quickExampleee = 3.1459038585;
std::cout << myFloorForWhateverReason(quickExamplee  * 100.) / 100. << std::endl;
```

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, please try to expand on your answer, describe why it works explain how it works. Your post was marked as low quality so this post can definitely be improved!